# HttpSession changes with each call to GWT-RPC service

Tags: java, session, gwt, gwt-rpc, sessionid

I have an GWT-RPC service with two methods, test and login.

I call the methods in this order, printing out the session information each time:

login()

```
Session Information:
ID: odl0h9578zww
isNew: true
```

test()

```
Session Information:
ID: lqv4leczh3ke
isNew: true
```

As can be seen here, both calls have a different session ID.

On the client side in the onSuccess for each of these calls I print out the value of the JSESSIONID cookie:

```
login(), JESSIONID cookie found, value is od10h9578zww
test(), JESSIONID cookie found, value is lqv4leczh3ke
```

If I hit refresh, I get the following (which is what I expected the first time):

login()

```
Session Information:
ID: mgn1uvuzdwx3
isNew: false
```

test()

```
Session Information:
ID: mgn1uvuzdwx3
isNew: false
```

Can anyone explain why, before a refresh, each call gets a new session ID?

Comment: You might want to inspect the HTTP response and request headers to see if a cookie is actually set, which is necessary for most session handling systems.

Comment: I had each call's onSuccess print the value of the JSESSIONID cookie."login(), JSESSION cookie found, value is 1jwufooxmt8w4", "test(), JSESSION cookie found, value is 1rrjupbo719fa"

Comment: @hudsonb have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the expiration time of session.